# Structure Padding in C

Tags: c, structure

If I have a structure definition in C of the following

```
typedef struct example 
{
  char c;
  int ii;
  int iii;
};
```

What should be the memory allocated when I declare a variable of the above structure type.
example ee;

and also what is structure padding and if there is any risk associated with structure padding?

Comment: why don't you compile some code and test?

Comment: Padding is compiler and architecture dependent. One risk for example is sending the struct over the network as is - since padding on the other end might be different

Comment: In C when you declare a `struct` variable you have to use the `struct` keyword before the typename. Are you actually using C++ or are you just learning C from C++ and have some habits left over?

Comment: @Drakosha: Endianness and size is also different.  It has never been safe to serialize arbitrary structures directly.

Comment: typedef struct dadida 
{
  char c;
  int ii;
  int iii;
} example;

Answer (score 10):

Try it.  It may be different on different systems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h> /* for offsetof */
struct example { char c; int ii; int iii; };
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("offsetof(struct example, c) == %zd\n", offsetof(struct example, c));
    printf("offsetof(struct example, ii) == %zd\n", offsetof(struct example, ii));
    printf("offsetof(struct example, iii) == %zd\n", offsetof(struct example, iii));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
offsetof(struct example, c) == 0
offsetof(struct example, ii) == 4
offsetof(struct example, iii) == 8
```

Note that `sizeof(char) == 1`, but there are four bytes before the `ii` field.  The extra three bytes are padding.  Padding exists to make sure that data types are lined up on the correct boundaries for your processor.

If a processor makes an unaligned access, various things can happen:

- The access is slower (most x86)
- The access must be handled by the kernel and is INCREDIBLY slow (various PowerPC) (This caused some computer games to run very slow on fast PPC 603 processors when they run just fine on slower PPC 601 processors.)
- The program crashes (various SPARC)

I know of no known risks with padding.  The only problem that really happens is that two programs compiled with different compilers (GCC vs MSVC has been known to cause this) use different padding and cannot share structures.  This can also cause crashes if code from different compilers is linked together.  Since padding is often specified by the platform ABI, this is rare.

Comment: One risk of padding is, that a newbie coder uses structs to format binary data sent over a network to another machine. Say this structure contained some buffer length information, you figure the rest.

Comment: That's not a problem with padding, that's a problem with not checking your buffer sizes.  If you don't check your buffer sizes, you have a buffer overflow whether or not padding is different.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal 32 bit it should take 12 bytes - the `c` field will be padded. This is architecture and compiler depended, however.

You can always use a `pragma` for the compiler to declare the alignment for the structure (and for some compilers, change the default alignment).